# for each loop with a second boolean parameter

Tags: java, foreach

Is there anyone here who know how do this:

```
boolean condition = true;
for(int i=0; i<list.size() && condition; i++){
    if (***)
        condition = false;
}
```

with a for each loop, like that:

```
boolean condition = true;
for(String s : list && condition){
    if (***)
        condition = false;
}
```

I know the second loop will not work, but I would like to have the same behaviour without using the killing mortal ugly instruction "break".

Comment: `break` is exactly what you should use here. It's a delightful instruction! You should become better friends with it. It's way more readable to me, even in the `for` case.

Comment: Nothing wrong with break.

Comment: Where does `condition` depend on? A simple possibility would be to filter `list` so that each element has to be processed and the elements which have not to be processed are filtered out.

Comment: Using break is a whole lot cleaner than putting the for loop in a try/catch block and throwing an exception when you wish to exit

Comment: @Smutje : Imagine a function to search for a specific ID in the object's list, when the ID is found the loop doesn't need to finish iterating.

I had learn at school to not use break instruction, it's make code unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Use break statement:

```
for(String s: list) {
   if (....) {
       break;
   }
}
```

BTW you can do it with any kind of loop and IMHO this is preferable because is more readable.

Comment: OP doesn't want break statement.

Comment: Oh, sorry. OP will have to understand that `break` is not ugly but one of the nice features introduced into C language ~45 (oh, my god) years ago.

Comment: Haha thanks for the answer. I'm surprise to read that all of you, would use break.
I don't like this instruction because it's not well readable and source of errors.
GOTO is an old feature too and it's not a readable way to code.

Comment: There is a serious difference between `goto` from one side and `break`+ `continue` from other. Goto can jump anywhere in your method including jumping to upper lines. Break and continue work for loops only. In fact break is usable in `switch` operator too. So, both break and continue are predictable: you do not have to look for the place where they jump.

Comment: Yes true. break is more readable as goto.

Answer (score 0):

break is not ugly at all!!

```
boolean condition=true;
for ( String s : list ) {
    if ( !condition ) break;
    ...
    if () condition=false;
}
```